# Sending File Over Serial Connection

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to write a windows forms application in visual c++ that sends GCode to a 3D printer. GCode can be read the same as any text file and there is only one GCode command for the printer per line of the file.

My goal is to pass the first line/command of the file to the printer, wait for the acknowledgement from the printer, which is a string that says "ok", then move to the next line of the file and pass it, etc. It is my first time programming with windows forms applications and I am uncertain on how to do this. My idea for the code would look something along the lines of this pseudocode, but I am open to suggestions if there is a better way.

Edit: I've updated my code to what I have so far. I still haven't figured out how to wait for the acknowledgement signal, "ok", from the serial connection or how to make this run in its own thread.

```
    String^ fileName = "C:\\LUPrint\\profiles\\graphene\\temp.gcode";
    try
    {
        StreamReader^ din = File::OpenText(fileName);

        String^ str;
        int count = 0;
        while ((str = din->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
        {
            count++;
            this->serialPort->WriteLine() = str;
            // Find way to wait for ack
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<FileNotFoundException^> (e))
            this->textBox1->Text = "File not found";
        else
            this->textBox1->Text = "Problem reading file";
    }
```

Comment: This looks fine as long as you run in in a different thread. Otherwise you'll block gui thread and your application will stop responding until sending is finished.

Comment: @genpfault: It's C++/CLI syntax which only works in Microsoft's compiler.  The [tag:visual-c++] is correct, but [tag:c++] is not, which I'll fix now.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski: Thanks for looking it over. Any advice on how to run it on a different thread? I've never done that before.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for fixing that, I'm new to the website and I'm trying to figure it all out.

Comment: WinApi i pressume? Which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Not sure if this answers your question but I'm using the Default C++ Language Standard for Visual Studio 2019. I set up the project using a CLR Empty Project.